# Is it possible to capture a queen directly in front of the king?

Tags: rules, check, kings, captures

Can the king capture a queen directly in front of him when he is in check ?

Comment: If the queen isn’t protected by another piece, yes

Comment: [Can the king capture his attacker?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/2703/26335)